# Code working on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing ASP.NET application wherein code is working fine on local IIS for both desktop and mobile.
But, when I copied the code to production server, it's working fine for desktop but not on mobile. I am struggling to resolve this from past few days but still no success yet.

This is the error:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    BasePage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +368
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +772

This is my base page code where it seems to have problem:

```
HtmlGenericControl liItem1 = new HtmlGenericControl();

liItem1 = (HtmlGenericControl)this.Master.FindControl("logtop_bar");

liItem1.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block");
```

I don't understand the logic why it's throwing error only for small screen mobile devices.

But the same doesn't reproduce on local environments.

Comment: Does "FindControl" actually find the logtop_bar on mobile? If you step into a debugger (put Chrome in mobile mode using your dev tools), do you see an issue? Or, you can always output text to the screen to see what it is.

Comment: I installed some plugin in chrome.This is easy to shuffle b/w mobile device and desktop view.It seems when i am switching to mobile view.

Comment: FindControl is throwing null,Though not sure why..

Comment: ASP.NET has build-in system of recognizing so called "browser capabilities" and adaptive rendering (they're based on browser user agent string). Some of the newer browsers were added via windows updates. Make sure your production server is up-to-date in terms of window updates with your dev server. Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3k2ssx2.aspx

Comment: Thanks,I will check the environments settings in production server.Meanwhile i checked via chrome developer tools,The display is fine  when i change the emulator settings to iPhone.Absolutely no error,The moment i change the browser default settings.It will throw the same error

Comment: I mean when i change browser default setting to iphone via plugin.It is throwing null error,same as above

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Ondrej Svejdar] answer...
In your solution there is likely a Site.Master and a Site.Mobile.Master. The mechanism for choosing one or the other is likely not picking the Mobile version even though you are expecting it. Try this

```
// the assignment below is not needed since you are assigning it again on the very next line
//HtmlGenericControl liItem1 = new HtmlGenericControl();
HtmlGenericControl liItem1 = (HtmlGenericControl)this.Master.FindControl("logtop_bar");
// this line below will print which master page you are using
Response.Write(this.Master.MasterPageFile);
// only set the attribute if it is not null.
if (liItem1 != null) {
    liItem1.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block");
}
```

Additionally, if you are always setting the style (I see no conditionals) then just do so in the markup of the page.

Comment: Well litem is always null,Yes both the files are there.I finally avoided by writing the rules in web.config.This doesn't work for me at all.

Comment: if liItem is always null then it does not exist on the master page.

Comment: It is not always null,its null only for mobile pages.

Comment: then it doesn't exist on the mobile master page